# Oracle Apex 5.1 - Interactive grid throws error on update

Tags: oracle-apex

**What I am trying to do:**
I have setup a data load the user can use to import a CSV from another system which covers 90% of the required fields they need. I then highlight the incomplete fields queried via where clause incomplete_yn = 'Y'. I was hoping to allow the user to update the values all at once using an interactive grid and in the background set the incomplete_yn = 'N' for them.

**What is the issue**
When I click save I get an error

```
1 error has occurred
Ajax call returned server error ORA-01403: no data found for .
```

My theory is that after update it trys to locate the row for display but becuase the flag is set to 'N' it is no longer returned by the base query. This is by design I only want to show incomplete records.

**What I have tried**
I rewrote the the plsql that it does on update but this generates the same error.

Is there any way to avoid it looking for the row after update?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I am out of ideas, anyone know why the interactive grid would be querying data during or after an update? Doesn't seem to be a flexible item for apex 5, very little you can configure and no one knows what it is doing behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

two suggestions:

1. verifying you have the process for interactive grid Automatic row processing (DML)
2. creating a new interactive grid page based on the table, and only afterwords modify the setting

maybe this can help as well:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3937159?start=0&tstart=0